# React line chart shadows (Chart.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, chart.js

I have multiple charts in my React application created using the **react-chartjs-2** library. I am using the **Chart.register** method to apply a custom shadow effect to the line charts. This however applies the shadow to all of the chart components.

Here is the relevant code:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Line } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import { Chart, registerables } from 'chart.js';
Chart.register(...registerables);

const PriceGraph = ({ chartData, chartColour, chartFillColour }) => {

  const options = {
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: false,
      }
    },
    scales: {
      x: {
        grid: {
          display: true,
          drawBorder: true,
          drawOnChartArea: false,
        },
        ticks: {
          display: true,
        }
      },
      y: {
        grid: {
          display: false,
          drawBorder: true,
          drawOnChartArea: false,
        },
        ticks: {
          display: true,
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // Custom shadow for chart
  useEffect(() => {
    Chart.register({
      id: 'customShadow',
      beforeDraw: (chart) => {
        const ctx = chart.ctx;
        ctx.save();

        const originalLineDraw = ctx.stroke;
        ctx.stroke = function () {
          ctx.save();
          ctx.shadowColor = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)';
          ctx.shadowBlur = 10;
          ctx.shadowOffsetX = 4;
          ctx.shadowOffsetY = 4;
          originalLineDraw.apply(this, arguments);
          ctx.restore();
        };
      }
    });
  }, []);

  const data = {
    labels: chartData.labels,
    datasets: [
      {
        data: chartData.data,
        backgroundColor: chartFillColour,
        borderColor: chartColour,
        fill: true,
      }
    ]
  }

  return chartData.labels ? <Line data={data} options={options}/> : null;
}

export default PriceGraph;
```

How can I modify this code to apply a shadow effect only to the line chart rendered by the PriceGraph component, without affecting other chart components in my application?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you register a plugin, this is used for all charts instances in the application.
You should set it as an "inline" plugin, in the chart instance where you want to use it (hopefully react-chartjs-2 syntax is correct):

```
const myPlugin = {
      id: 'customShadow',
      beforeDraw: (chart) => {
        const ctx = chart.ctx;
        ctx.save();

        const originalLineDraw = ctx.stroke;
        ctx.stroke = function () {
          ctx.save();
          ctx.shadowColor = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)';
          ctx.shadowBlur = 10;
          ctx.shadowOffsetX = 4;
          ctx.shadowOffsetY = 4;
          originalLineDraw.apply(this, arguments);
          ctx.restore();
        };
      }
    };

return chartData.labels ? <Line data={data} options={options} plugins={[myPlugin]}/> : null;
```